# Is $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ closed under differentiation

Tags: real-analysis

I'm curious about the properties of the space of smooth functions with compact support, $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$. Specifically, I'm interested in whether this space is closed under the operation of differentiation. If we take a function $f$ that is in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ and differentiate it, is the resulting function guaranteed to also be in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, regardless of the support interval of $f$ potentially changing?

Could anyone provide references for further reading on this topic?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $K$ is the compact support of a smooth $F$. Let $f$ be the gradient of $F$. Is $f$ also supported on $K$ and therefore compactly supported?  Yes. Simply because on $K^c$ $F$ is identically zero, by definition, and the derivative at points there may be computed by only working on $K^c$ - it being open! - and the derivative of zero is zero. So $C_c^\infty$ is closed under differentiation.